# jQuery How to trigger a function after multiple, random drop events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, event-handling, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop project with to print buttons, one which prints the page as is (before the user drags or drops anything) and a second which I disabled using JavaScript on load. How do I activate the second button after ALL the draggables have been dropped?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable({ revert: 'invalid', cursor: 'move', snapTolerance: '0px' }), 
    $("#dropcrown").droppable({ accept: '#crown'});
    $( "#dropneck" ).droppable({ accept: '#neck' });
    $( "#dropback" ).droppable({ accept: '#back' });
    $( "#droptail" ).droppable({ accept: '#tail' });
    $( "#dropwing" ).droppable({ accept: '#wing' });
    $( "#dropeye" ).droppable({ accept: '#eye' });
    $( "#dropbeak" ).droppable({ accept: '#beak' });
    $( "#dropcheek" ).droppable({ accept: '#cheek' });  
    $( "#dropbreast" ).droppable({ accept: '#breast' });
    $( "#dropbelly" ).droppable({ accept: '#belly' });
    $( "#dropfoot" ).droppable({ accept: '#foot' });
     $('#button2', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $('#button2', this).addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
                });


            $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#dropcrown, #dropneck ,#dropback, #droptail, #dropwing, #dropeye, #dropbeak, #dropcheek, #dropbreast, #dropbelly, #dropfoot" ).droppable({tolerance:'touch',
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this )
                    .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                        var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            $(dropped).detach().css({top: 15,left: 7}).appendTo(droppedOn);
            $('#button', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#button', this).addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );

            }
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if($('#labels').html() == ""){
            $('#button2', this).removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#button2', this).removeClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
  //do something
}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI `Droppable` has a [`drop` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop). Hook it on the droppables, and when you see the event, look in the container you're taking them out of. Is it empty? Trigger the code you want to trigger (for instance, enabling the button).

Comment: @user1333422: Code is worth a thousand words. The above is a general guide, but if you're having trouble applying it, ask a question showing your code trying to do the above, and people will be happy to help you debug it.

Comment: Hi @T.J Crowder and Roko C. Buljan, I've added my code to the question. #button is the active button on document load and #button2 should only become active after all the drop events have been fired.

Comment: Also, #labels is the div that holds the draggables. I've tried to trigger the button activation once the div is empty with no luck